# Access local network SVN through Web VPN

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control

I'm facing some problems using VPN Web authentication:

We have a local protected network on which an https SVN server runs. 
Accessing it locally within Eclipse makes no problems.

We have external people which have to access this SVN through Web VPN.

The problem is, this web VPN only works in the specific web browser context, and we are not able to connect eclipse directly through this VPN then.

Accessing the VPN through the browser works though (but no commit/versioning is possible).

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved by activating the JSAM (Java secure application manager) on the WEB VPN. It activates the link between installed clients (external people) and specific IP Connections (allowed by gateway).